# Using Javascript how to get the pseudo CSS style of a dom node?

Tags: jquery, css, dom, pseudo-class

Hi I have an element (dom node) and it has a pseudo CSS hover CSS style. I want to use Javascript to get this CSS style, am in the Chrome web browser.

Comment: You want to get the individual styles of this element while it has `:hover` attached to it? i.e are you looking to enumerate each style defined in  `yourElement:hover { ... }`

Comment: I want to be able to get all of its :hover styles using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the computed styles (currently applied styles) of an element using `window.getComputedStyle(element)`

For your case, you can call the above when the element is hovered and use the saved style object later on for your purpose.

**Ref**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ur297/

**Code**:

```
var hoverStyles = false;
$('.foo').hover(function() {
    hoverStyles = window.getComputedStyle(this);
    printStyles(hoverStyles );
}, function() {});

function printStyles(_styles) {
    console.log('Color: ' + _styles.color);
    console.log('Background Color: ' + _styles.backgroundColor);
}
```

Comment: It helps, but I can only get the elements hover style when I hover over the element. I want to be able to get its hover style even when not hovering

Comment: That is trickier and involves quite a lot more work. In summary, it involves enumerating all stylesheets imported into the page, filtering out the :hover definition for the element of choice, and then fetching the styles defined within and parsing them out to values. I would say an overkill by far.

Answer (score 2):

```
  function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

and to get css like font-size

```
getStyle(document.getElementById("container"), "font-size");
```